# Action Buttons on Shiny R Not Working. What should I do?

Tags: r, shiny

I have to use action buttons as submit buttons. I don't want to use submit buttons because I don't want to submit all in one time and want to use submit buttons' Id in valueBox.

Anyway, I had coded but they shew only the buttons. They seemed not link to outputs.
My objective is use a action button to show many outputs. What should I do?

In UI: There are more inputs, but I cut. And they are placed in a box, in tabItem.

```
selectInput(inputId = "subject3", label = "",
      choices= c("-", data.frame(thelists[ ,6]))),
      numericInput(inputId = "longevity", label="Longevity", value = 1, min = 1),
      actionButton("submitbut1", "Save")),
```

In Server

```
function(input, output, session) {
observeEvent(input$submitbut1, {
  output$shcool <- renderText({ input$shcool})
  output$schsize <- renderText({ input$schsize})
  output$qualificationba <- renderText({ input$qualificationba})
  output$majorba1 <- renderText({ input$majorba1})
  output$majorba2 <- renderText({ input$majorba2})
  output$qualificationma <- renderText({ input$qualificationma})
  output$majorma <- renderText({ input$majorma})
  output$qualificationdoc <- renderText({ input$qualificationdoc})
  output$majordoc <- renderText({ input$majordoc})
  output$subject1 <- renderText({ input$subject1})
  output$subject2 <- renderText({ input$subject2})
  output$subject3 <- renderText({ input$subject3})
  output$studying <- renderText({ input$studying})
  output$longevity <- renderText({ input$longevity})  
})}
```

To appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `outputs` functions as values that are better stored as a `reactive` value. Here's a minimal app that I think solves what you are trying to do:

```r
    library(shiny)
    
    ui <- fluidPage(
    
      selectInput(inputId = "subject3", label = "",
                  choices= c("-", "checking")),
      numericInput(inputId = "longevity", label="Longevity", value = 1, min = 1),
      actionButton("submitbut1", "Save"),
      
      verbatimTextOutput("check"))
    
        
    
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      
      values <- reactive({
        
        req(input$submitbut1) #Take dependency on input$submitbut1
        
        list(isolate(input$subject3), isolate(input$longevity)) #isolate makes them loose evaluation when they change, so they are only evaluated when input$submitbut1 is clicked
        })  
      
      output$check <- renderPrint({values()})
      
      }
    
    
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, David. I run your code that the button work. But in my app, the button still does'n work. I will try more and more.